# Can you wire a 30A 2P standard circuit breaker "downstream" from a 60A GFCI 2p circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, circuit-breaker, gfci

Will this still provide GFCI protection?  Is this against code?  Does this represent a hazard?

I have a subpanel with a 60A GFCI circuit breaker, that I want to use that to feed to 2 30a 240v receptacles.  I'm looking to have GFCI protection on the lines, but also make sure the lines are protected for their rating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a 50 amp GFCI breaker on 15 amp circuit?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51156/can-i-use-a-50-amp-gfci-breaker-on-15-amp-circuit)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the opposite scenario of what I am describing.  Does it matter?

Comment: It's not at all the same. You're fine @JeremyHolovacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work fine. The GFI protection is on the feeder side so everything downstream will be protected.

Out of curiosity, why the need for GFCI protection?

Comment: Building an electric microbrewery in my basement :)  Thanks

Comment: See 215.9 for the applicable NEC cite, btw